# retrieve sharepoint site workflows

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I am trying to list all workflows within share point site collection with the link of the lists that they related to, I found it is possible using power shell code but I do not have access to share point administration farm, so how can I do it without using power shell.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use rest api to get all workflows
You can get all lists by rest api first.

```
/_api/web/lists
```

Then you can loop all list title and get WorkflowAssociations of all lists

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('[ListTitle]')/WorkflowAssociations
```